# Button does not fit the screen - how to shrink the rest of layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem with layout of Calendar - the "Done" button is not fully visible

[image]

The source of this layout is here I believe:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/d1db03631de67104f7d3b3da73eaeec28a80aef2/res/layout/recurrencepicker.xml

Any ideas how it should be fixed? I may shrink a little the area where month days are shown, but honestly I can't find where is the layout for them ... I know that there are two Views for months - one shows May, and the other shows part of June. I may shrink or even remove the June part but where is it

Comment: Try to increase the height of the button..

Comment: Did you try increasing the height of the button???

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the marginTop, make it `android:layout_marginTop="4dp"`, from

```
<com.android.calendar.recurrencepicker.LinearLayoutWithMaxWidth
                    android:id="@+id/weekGroup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Over there it is 8dp. Hope it will make some change in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the calender and the button are in the same layout, if not but them in one layout and make it's height `match_parent`, then give it a weight_sum of `1`, and assign weight for the calender `0.9` with a `0dp` height and for the button assign `0.1` weight with a `0dp` height also:

```
        <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/container_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/calendar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9">

                  <!--  calender layout contents  -->  

                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                   android:id="@+id/done_button"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="0.1" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just put them in another one inside this one in order to not to miss up with the current attitudes set to the layout in Line.24